# Html.Raw not working, debugging code does not match view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Working on a page that does not use the built-in validation.  When I have the following line in my code:

```
...
<tr class="@{ Html.Raw(Model.FieldsInError.Contains("FirstName") ? "" : "hidden"); }" id="valFirstName">
    <td colspan="2" class="text-danger">@Login.Error_FName</td>
</tr>
...
```

The output looks like:

```
<tr class="" id="valFirstName">
     <td colspan="2" class="text-danger">@Login.Error_FName</td>
</tr>
```

No matter what I put in the ?: block.  Tried ? "lard" : :"hidden" and that fails and always renders "" as well.

I've verified the Model.FieldsInError property is not null and has valid strings.  I've tried both a HashSet and a List.

When I debug and step through the view, the wrong areas are highlighted.

Using VS2013 sp5.

Comment: Why are you using `Html.Raw()`? - thats for outputting un-encoded html

Comment: Because inside of quotes you can't just say @Model.FieldsInError.Contains("SaveFailure") ? "" : " hidden" or the statement fails.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? - add a `class="hidden"` if `FieldsInError` does not contain "FirstName"?

Comment: Yes.  The `FieldsInError` list contains the name of all of the fields whose error text should be shown.

Comment: `@{ var className = Model.FieldsInError.Contains("FirstName") ? "hidden" : null; } <tr class="@className" id="...">...</tr>`

Comment: So it's a bug in the razor view engine?  Lame.  Would hate to do that for all 8 fields.  Have another fix I'll try, do it client-side by json encoding the array and walking the list so that when new items are added I don't have to duplicate code.  But your answer is valid, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129859/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ed-williams).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like a bug in the Razor view engine.  Stephen's idea of breaking the logic out of the quotes did in fact work.  Much appreciation.

So for anyone else seeing this, just bust the logic out of the class definition like so:

```
@{ var className = Model.FieldsInError.Contains("FirstName") ? "hidden" : null; } 
<tr class="@className" id="...">...</tr>
```

This leaves the logic on the server.

For my own code, because I didn't want to do that for every field, I just did the following at the end of the page so that the fields are shown by client-side logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        var errors = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FieldsInError));

        for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            $("#" + errors[i]).removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This does, however, create a dependency on the view structure inside the controller which is evil, so I'd recommend Stephen's approach to keep the view and controller independent as per the MVC methodology.

Comment: The Razor engine will omit an attribute if it is only assigned a null value. So, `class="@(Model.FieldsInError.Contains("FirstName") ? null : "hidden")"` should work.

Comment: @TiesonT. This should be an answer and I would vote it up! Also the reason it's "looks like a bug" is because @{ Html.Raw(""); } just executes the Raw() method and throws away the return value. @Html.Raw() prints the value.